# ViewPager not showing TabLayout containing the title of the fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity where I wanted a `view pager`. So I defined 5 fragments and followed what is shown in the google documentation for the view pager. But I am not able to see the title of the pages defined for the TabLayout.

Activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_kannada);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

        //Adapter to populate ViewPager
        CategoryAdapter adapter = new CategoryAdapter(this,getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
```

Adapter code :

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

//Number of pages in the ViewPager
private final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
//Context of the app
private Context mContext;

public CategoryAdapter(Context context,FragmentManager fm){
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Inside Custom Adapter",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return new ChatFragment();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return new FamilyFragment();
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return new ColorsFragment();
    } else if (position == 3){
        return new PhrasesFragment();
    }
    else {
        return new NumbersFragment();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_PAGES;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_numbers);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_family);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_colors);
    } else if(position == 3) {
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_phrases);
    }
    else{
        return mContext.getString(R.string.category_chat);
    }
}
}
```

fragment :

```
public class NumbersFragment extends Fragment {

public NumbersFragment(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container,false);

    String[] languages = {"Kannada","Tamil","Telugu","Malayalam","Bengali"}; //String array with language name
    ListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,languages);
    ListView listView = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Inside Numbers Fragment",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return rootView;
}
}
```

activity_kannada :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.arqamahmad.languageslearnandtalk.Kannada">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />


</LinearLayout>
```

So why is this problem happening as I can't see any other way to do. I am just getting the fragments as normal pages without the TabLayout at top.

Comment: I don't see what is the problem, What happens if you try to swipe to another position ? doesn't it work ?

Comment: @Gil No the problem is that the tabLayout containing the title of the page is not showing.

Comment: would you post your activity_kannada.xml ?

Comment: @Sarah sure. Done.

Comment: @arqam try placing the TabLayout tag above the ViewPager

Comment: @Sarah still the same. My github repo : https://github.com/torrtuga/Learning-Indian-Languages

Comment: @arqam it is working fine and the tabs are all shown, try cleaning the project!

Comment: @Sarah Yeah Thanks. It is working.Damn this Android Studio.